# How to get previuos item of Dropdown using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to get the previously selected value of a dropdown control using jquery or javascript.
How can i get this?
I tried with prev() selector of jquery but failed

```
$(ddlStatus).find("option").prev(":selected").attr("text");
```

if ddlStatus has items like A,B,C,D,E When the page loads B is selected but when user changes the item {let's say) E then I want previously selected i.e B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it like this (not optimized but works):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(ddl).data('lastSelected', $(ddl).val());
});
$(ddlstatus).change(function(){
   var lastSelected = $(this).data('lastSelected');
   $(this).data('prevLastSelected', lastSelected);
   $(this).data('lastSelected', $(this).val());
});
```

Then, to know the previously selected anytime, you just do:

```
var previouslySelectedValue = $(ddl).data('prevLastSelected');
```

What's good about this code is that the state is saved **in the element** and you **don't use global vars**, so it can be applied to any number of select boxes

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Something broadly like this should do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever a selection is made, save the value. On a new selection, you will then have the old value saved until you overwrite it.

You cannot do this dorectly, as you are after historical information - prev is about the ordering not the timing.

Comment: save a value to global variable and also save it onLoad

Comment: Correct,  I too would a variable holding the history

Comment: It's better to save the value in the element itself, and avoid global vars. I did it in my answer

Answer (score 1):

here is a example:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="one" selected="selected">one</option>
  <option value="two">two</option>
  <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
var prev = null; //global
var cur = $('#myselect').val();//global
var flag = true;// global

$('#myselect').change(function() {
    if (flag) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = $(this).val();
        flag = false;
    } else {
        prev = cur;
        cur = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer helped me & i voted +1 .maybe some other guy downvoted u